# XSD child element alternatives

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an XSD where I have a definition for a type. That definition is made of the base type and some additional type-specific attributes.

For example, there are these two types:

```xml
<type>
    <baseType kind="string"/>
    <stringData1>...</stringData1>
    <stringData2>...</stringData2>
</type>
```

and

```xml
<type>
    <baseType kind="int"/>
    <intData1>...</intData1>
    <intData2>...</intData2>
</type>
```

There are already definitions for the two different `type` elements, but I do not know how to set them both as alternatives in a parent element. I.e. how do I define this element in XSD:

```xml
<types>
    <type>
        <!-- either int or string type -->
    </type>
<types/>
```

Answer (score 0):

XML Schema 1.0 will not support this XML style - not unless you are happy to allow baseType='string' followed by intData tags. You will fall foul of the Unique Particle Attribution rule. The validating XML parser must be able to work out where it is in the XSD by examining *only* tag names and without looking ahead or backtracking. In this case, the parser would only know which type to use after encountering the  or  tag.

You could model this format in XSD 1.0 if you are willing to remove the baseType attribute from the XSD and use an xsi:type attribute to signal which complex type to use.

I'm fairly sure that you could do it in XSD 1.1, but I'm not able to advise you on how to do that.